# Am I setting up the radius or the height incorrectly?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I am stuck on a problem that asks to find the volume using cylindrical shells within the curves $y=x^2, x=y^2$ rotated around $y=-3$. I derived the formula: $2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left(y+3\right)\left(\sqrt{y}-y^{2}\right)\right)dy$, but my checker says my answer is wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks fine to me. You can check the washer method, it gives the same answer. $V=23\pi/10$

Comment: @Andrei I was getting $-23pi/10$, since I did $y^2-sqrt(y)$. I changed it to $sqrt(y)-y^2$ and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: How did you get negative? Between $0$ and $1$ you have $\sqrt y>y^2$, $y+3>0$. If you integrate a positive function, you will get a positive result.

Comment: I was doing top minus bottom rather than right minus left. Thanks for your help!